# Laravel 5.6 shopping cart based on session token authentication issue

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, shopping-cart

I created a custom e-commerce system based on laravel. The shopping cart is identified by the session token of laravel (**session['_token']**) and is devided in a cart table and a cartProduct table. The whole system is working as expected.

Unfortunately the **session['_token']** is changed as soon as the users has succesfully logged in. After this the whole cart of the old session is not correct idetified because the token has changed.

Now my questions:

- How can I prevent Laravel from changing the session['_token'] after log-in?
- Is this recommandable or can some security issues occur?
- If not: How to relate the shopping cart to the user before and after login?

If you need further information about the system please let me know in the comments and I will provide you with details.

**cart - table**: [image]

**cart_products - table**: [image]

Comment: When a user logs in, can't you pick up what ever is in the cart at the time of the login, then re-save it to the currently logged in user? By default Laravel fires a login event that you would just have to listen to or just update it in the login controller which you could do just by POSTing the contents of the shopping cart at point of login.

Comment: Of course, this is a good option. Unfortunately I never used the event listener. I will have a look to the documentation regarding this topic.

Comment: You could also bcrypt an array of cart_products ids in a cookie. What if the user has 2 logins with 2 different physical addresses? "Oh, wrong login. Logout. Login again." I noticed websites like Lazada take this approach. Once the cart items are handled (checked out), the cookie gets deleted (or emptied). Because, from then on, the items are linked to a user in the database.

Comment: The cookie is an approach ONLY if the user is not logged in. You could, if the user logs out, still send the items to a cookie. If a user logs in, send the cookie back to the database. A middleware can handle this.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey this is also possible with the advantages you mentioned. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution. I modified the LoginController and updated the sendLoginResponse method to my needs:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        // save old session token (shopping cart is related to this one)

        $old_session_token = session()->get('_token');

        // regenerate new session (prevent session fixation)
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        // get new session token
        $new_session_token = session()->get('_token');

        // update session token in cart table

        $shopping_cart = Cart::where('session_token', $old_session_token)->first();

        $shopping_cart->session_token = $new_session_token;

        $shopping_cart->save();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

This code updates the old token with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea safe old session id before attempt login

1. Change action name in route

   ```
   Route::post("/login", 'LoginController@doLogin');
   ```
2. Modify LoginController

   ```
   class LoginController extends Controller {

      use AuthenticatesUsers;

      private $old_session_id;

      public function doLogin(Request $request) {
        //remember old session id
        $this->old_session_id = $request->session()->getId();

        //call AuthenticatesUsers trait method
        return $this->login($request);
      }

      //override trait method
      protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
         //sync cart
         $cart = Cart::whereSessionId($this->old_session_id)->first();
      }

   }
   ```